# Python and Gtk+3 Entry problems

Tags: python, twitter, open-source, gtk3, pyobject

Greetings guys and girls!

I am new in programming Gtk+ and need a "decent" opensource twitter client and I can't find one, so I'm developing one that 'll be opensource. I'm using Gtk+3 and Python (PyGObject not PyGtk), and I'm having 2 problems with my Entry:
1 - can't connect a handler to these  signals : `"deleted-text"` and `"inserted-text"` to an to my tweet_text that is a Entry. I tryied `self.tweet_text.connect("inserted-text", self.on_tweet)` and `self.tweet_text.set_property("inserted-text", self.on_tweet)` but it keeps failing.
2 - can't make my tweet_text multine.

I searched the documentation here http://readthedocs.org/docs/python-gtk-3-tutorial/en/latest/ but I can't find nothing related with it. And a also searched the C documentation related to Gtk+3.

I apreciate if someone help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `inserted-text` signal is emitted by `Gtk.EntryBuffer` objects, not by `Gtk.Entry` ones. To connect to that signal, you should use something like this:

```
entry = Gtk.Entry()
entry_buffer = entry.get_buffer()
entry_buffer.connect('inserted-text', callback)
```